# Encontrar um componente pelo name

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Tenho uma String:

```
var
  vMinhastring : string;
begin
  vMinhastring := 'Edit1';
```

No meu form eu tenho um Compomente Tedit com o name Edit1. Como eu passo algum valor pro meu Edit1, utilizando o a vMinhastring como nome do Componente?

```
  vMinhastring.text := 'batatinha';
```

Estou Tentando fazer assim, mas estou tendo problemas:

```
contElem := 1;
Rdb1:= TRadioGroup.Create(TabSheet1);
Rdb1.Parent:= TabSheet1;
Rdb1.OnExit := Validacao;
Rdb1.Name:='Rdb'+IntToStr(contElem);
Rdb1.Items.Add('C');

Edit := TMaskEdit.Create(TabSheet1);
Edit.Parent:= TabSheet1;
Edit.Name:='Edit'+IntToStr(contElem);
Edit.Clear;
Edit.EditMask := ('!99;1;');

contElem := 2;
Rdb1:= TRadioGroup.Create(TabSheet1);
Rdb1.Parent:= TabSheet1;
Rdb1.OnExit := Validacao;
Rdb1.Name:='Rdb'+IntToStr(contElem);
Rdb1.Items.Add('C');

Edit := TMaskEdit.Create(TabSheet1);
Edit.Parent:= TabSheet1;
Edit.Name:='Edit'+IntToStr(contElem);
Edit.Clear;
Edit.EditMask := ('!99;1;');
```

Criei uma procedure:

```
procedure TFCad_AnaliseDeTendencias.Validacao(Sender: TObject);
var
 name, name2 :string;
 i : integer;
begin
   name := TRadioGroup(Sender).Name;
   name2 := '';
   for i := 1 to Length(name) do
   begin
      if name[i] in ['0'..'9'] then
         name2 := name2 + name[i];
   end;
   name2 := 'Edit'+name2;
   TMaskEdit(FindComponent(name2)).Text := '01'; //Esta dando erro aqui.
end;
```

Está dando erro de

> Access violation at address

Comment: O que você precisa não é `Edit1.Text = vMinhastring`; ?

Comment: não é isso que preciso.

Comment: Você vai precisar também, especificar o tipo do componente. Ex: 'Edit1' do tipo 'TEdit'. Tendo isso em m]aos você vai trabalhar com Typecast e/ou RTTI. Se precisar de um exemplo é só pedir, mas se você der uma pesquisada sobre typecast e rtti você vai entender oque estou dizendo.

Comment: Então me parece que você quer achar um controle dinamicamente no form tendo apenas o nome dele, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo @Pagotti

Comment: @VictorTadashi tem algum exemplo, usando Typecast?

Comment: @TiagoCasanova peguei sua ultima edição e não ocorre erro algum, da uma revisada!

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, montei um protótipo com RTTI que fica melhor. Segue o código:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    function CriarComponente(AClassType: TClass; AName: String; AParent: TWinControl): TComponent;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Rtti;

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }



procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  CriarComponente(GetClass(Edit1.Text), Edit2.Text, Panel1);

end;



function TForm1.CriarComponente(AClassType: TClass; AName: String; AParent: TWinControl): TComponent;
var
  RttiContext: TRttiContext;
  RttiInstanceType: TRttiInstanceType;
  Value: TValue;
begin

  RttiInstanceType                       := (RttiContext.GetType(AClassType) as TRttiInstanceType);
  Value                                  := RttiInstanceType.GetMethod('Create').Invoke(RttiInstanceType.metaClassType, [self]);
  (Value.AsObject as TWinControl).Parent := AParent;

end;



procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  RegisterClasses([TButton, TForm, TEdit]);
end;

end.
```

Na tela do programa, eu adicionei 2 edits onde você vai informar o Tipo do componente e o nome dele, um botão para executar, e um painel para ser o parent dos componentes.

Obs.: É necessario regitrar as classes que voce pode criar, ex: `RegisterClasses([TButton, TForm, TEdit]);`

Comment: Na realidade o que ele perguntou não é como criar um novo componente e sim como adicionar um texto a um já existente apenas sabendo o `name`

Comment: @Sorack, tens razão

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função [`System.Classes.TComponent.FindComponent`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Classes_TComponent_FindComponent.html):

```
TEdit(FindComponent(vMinhastring)).Text := 'Meu texto';
```

> **FindComponent**
>
> **Original:** FindComponent returns the component in the Components property array with the name that matches the string in the AName parameter.
>
> **Tradução livre:** FindComponent retorna o componente na propriedade array Component com o nome que corresponda a string no parâmetro AName.

Answer (score 0):

Veja isso:

```
procedure TForm13.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var
   tabSheet: TTabSheet;
   AComponent: TComponent;
   aIndex: Integer;
begin
   aIndex:=-1;

   AComponent := FindComponent('TabSheet1');
   if Assigned(AComponent) then
     if AComponent is TTabSheet then
       aIndex := TTabSheet(AComponent).PageIndex; //get the index of the 'TabSheet1'  

   tabSheet := TTabSheet.Create(PageControl1);
   tabSheet.PageControl := PageControl1;
   tabSheet.Caption := 'My TabSheet'+IntToStr(PageControl1.PageCount);
   if aIndex>-1 then
     tabSheet.PageIndex := aIndex; //Set the index of the new TabSheet
end;
```